# RichTextBox control, making non-URLs hyperlinks?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hyperlink, richtextbox

In a richtextbox I see there's DetectURLs and an event to go along with that...

Is there a way to set up a word or series of words to act as a hyperlink even though they are not a hyperlink? My specific use is that I'm writing a ticker program that will scroll information across the bottom of the screen, I would like for some information to be clickable without putting the long, messy URL of the target. Anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Links with arbitrary text in a RichTextBox**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox