# Winform richtextbox detecturl can't detect Japanese character in hyperlink

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink

So, what I'm doing is that I have hyperlinks in my richtextbox. These hyperlinks direct the user to Jisho dictionary website. The said hyperlinks look like [http://jisho.org/search/本](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%AC)

Now, the problem is that the detecturls function of richtextbox only detects http://jisho.org/search/
It just stops detecting the url when it encounters the Japanese character.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to first use HttpUtility.UrlEncode method to encode those http links to  "http://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%AC" instead of containing Japanese characters, then RichTextBox control can detect them

but if you still must use jap characters in the richtextbox , maybe you can reference following link
[RichTextBox control, making non-URLs hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526857/richtextbox-control-making-non-urls-hyperlinks?rq=1)